# Dynamic MAP parameter for MapCache + MapServer

Tags: mapserver, mapcache

The MapServer and MapCache are installed on the Ubuntu machine, all works fine. However, the specific of developed system is that the displayed through WMS data often have different map files created. The question is - can the **MAP** parameter be dynamic, i.e. fetched from the original request to MapCache?

So, basically I want to make request like

> http://31.227.56.57/mapcache/?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=localmapserver&HEIGHT=1024&WIDTH=1024&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=11271098.442818949,6261721.35712164,11897270.578531113,6887893.492833804&map=/s/some/file.map

The example of working config

```
  <source name="vmap1" type="wms">
      <getmap>
         <params>
            <FORMAT>image/png</FORMAT>
            <LAYERS>result_0</LAYERS>
            <TRANSPARENT>true</TRANSPARENT>
            <MAP>/s/temp/mapfiles/RSCnuQp7iH.map</MAP>
            <!--<MAP>{MAP}</MAP>-->
         </params>
      </getmap>
      <http>
         <url>http://31.227.56.55/cgi-bin/mapserv</url>
      </http>
   </source>

   <tileset name="localmapserver">
      <source>vmap1</source>
      <cache>disk</cache>
      <grid>WGS84</grid>
      <grid>GoogleMapsCompatible</grid>
      <format>PNG</format>
      <metatile>5 5</metatile>
      <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
      <expires>3600</expires>
   </tileset>
```